# easily accessing data in matlab matrices loaded with scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, mat-file, matlab-load

When I load in a .mat file with scipy.io.loadmat, I get a data structure which is difficult to deal with because I have to guess at what level in the structure the data is contained. The numpy or scipy representation wraps everything in deep lists. Printing it doesn't usually help because it contains a lot of data. For example:

```
from scipy.io import loadmat
mat = loadmat("data.mat")
val = mat["someattribute"] # not what I want, the data I can iterate over is one layer deeper (len(val) == 1)
val = mat["someattribute"][0] # len(val) is some big value
```

Is there some easy way to access these things without having to worry about their representation? I recently switched from python 2.6.6 to 2.7.3 and noticed that the  representation in the numpy/scipy libraries changed (and hence my code broke).

Comment: Sorry. I would prefer not to post the data. But know that, as I stated below, the matrix is given to me as a dictionary.

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted out?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get away with

```
val = mat['someattribute'].ravel()
```

which will flatten `val` to a 1D `np.array` if you know it is 1D data or

```
val = mat['someattribute'].squeeze()
```

which will remove all the `len=1` dimensions [(doc)](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html)

Comment: The matrix is given to me as a dictionary.

Comment: @anonymous you should include that information in your question.  I guessed (wrong) that you were trying get out an array.  You will get better answers the more clear your question is.